# CS50 readability - calculation is off

Tags: c++, cs50

I am doing CS50 Readability problem set. I am trying to count the words in a given passage. When I code the calculation within main I get the correct answer:

```cpp
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int letters;

int main(void)//
{
  // user prompted for input
  string input = get_string("Input: "); //prompt user to input text

  for (int i=0; i < strlen(input); i++)
  {
    if (isalpha(input[i]))
    {
      letters++;
    }
  }
    printf("letters %i\n", letters);
}
```

But when I do the calculation outside of main it returns 0. I cannot see why this is happening

```cpp
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int count_letters(string input);
int letters;

int main(void)//
{
  // user prompted for input
  string input = get_string("Input: "); //prompt user to input text

  printf("Letters: %i\n", letters);
}

int count_letters(string input)
{
  letters = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++)
  {
    if (isalpha(input[i]))
    {
      letters++;
    }
  }
return letters;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't not call your count_letter function in the second program in the main. So that the letters variable is not calculated. You just defined your function on your top of the program. Make sure to call your function

```
int main(void)//
{
  // user prompted for input
  string input = get_string("Input: "); //prompt user to input text

  // Called your function here
  printf("Letters: %i\n", count_letters(input));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second program doesn't actually call the function.  Add:

```
letters = count_letters(input);
```